# Inside a function that accepts either numbers or arrays as args, how to efficiently operate on those args regardless of type?

Tags: javascript

Imagine you've got a function that accepts either 1D coords, 2D coords, or 3D coords as arguments. At function call, if the user wanted to pass a handful of 1D coords, they'd pass simple numbers, e.g.:

```
myFunction(30, 50);
```

But if they wanted to pass 2D or 3D coords instead, they'd pass these coords as arrays / vector values, e.g.:

```
myFunction([30, 40], [50, 60]);
```

Now, inside the function definition, say you want to run various ops and equations that involve the passed coords. Because you need to deal with one of two different arg types (numbers vs arrays), you might want to format the statements differently for each data type, and so you might end up repeating a bunch of statements, which is inefficient. For the sake of argument, imagine that you can't do simple vector math on the array args, and instead you need to loop and break them out by index:

```js
function myFunction( coord1, coord2 ) {
    let myVar1 = 0, myVar2 = 0, myVar3 = 0;

    // if args are arrays
    if ( Array.isArray( coord1 ) ) {
        myVar1 = [], myVar2 = [], myVar3 = [];

        for (let i = 0; i < coord1.length; i++) {
            myVar1[i] = coord1[i] * coord2[i];
            myVar2[i] = myVar1[i] / coord2[i] + myVar1[i];
            myVar3[i] = coord1[i] * (coord2[i] / myVar2[i]);
        }

    // else if args are scalar
    } else {
        myVar1 = coord1 * coord2;            // this
        myVar2 = myVar1 / coord2 + myVar1;   // is
        myVar3 = coord1 * (coord2 / myVar2); // inefficient
    }

    return myVar3;
}
```

The equations above are nonsense, but they're just for illustration. **How would you avoid repeating yourself here?** I can think of several ways to DRY (assigning the scalar args to single-index arrays; or turning chunks of the equations into messy and hard-to-read "logical or" expressions (e.g., `myVar[i] = (coord1[i] || coord1) * (coord2[i] || coord2)`); or rigging up an array of objects or something), but I don't really like any of them, and I'm still a novice, so I don't know what it is I don't know. Any experienced coders want to weigh in on best practices for handling a situation like this?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the approaches you came up with and why you don't like them

Comment: Convert non-array arguments to arrays at the top of the function: `coord1 = Array.isArray(coord1) ? coord1 : [coord1]` or `coord1 = [].concat(coord1)`

Comment: Sounds like the easiest solution (especially since all your "vector math" is just element-wise) would be to wrap 1D values in an array of a single value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For element-wise repetition, just have the function for arrays call the scalar function:

```
function myFunctionArr(coords1, coords2) {
    const results = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < coords1.length; i++) {
        results[i] = myFunctionScalar(coords1[i], coords2[i]);
    }
    return results;
}
function myFunctionScalar(coord1, coord2) {
    const myVar1 = coord1 * coord2;
    const myVar2 = myVar1 / coord2 + myVar1;
    return coord1 * (coord2 / myVar2);
}
```

Of course you can also make this into an overloaded function, like

```
function myFunction(coord1, coord2) {
    if (Array.isArray(coord1)) { // args are arrays
        return myFunctionArr(coord1, coord2);
    } else { // args are scalar
        return myFunctionScalar(coord1, coord2);
    }
}
```

You can even abstract the element-wise application of a function on multiple array elements in a helper function (also provided by many functionally-minded libraries):

```
return zipWith(myFunctionScalar, coords1, coords2)
```

Comment: late reply, but thanks for introducing me to zipWith (had to Google for it, but figured it out for my own code too)

Answer (score 1):

If your generic function should always have homogenous parameters and return type, then start by defining the base-case for your function using primitives only, then use a wrapper function to traverse your parameters and apply your base-case function to each element:

```js
function myFunction (coord1, coord2) {
  const myVar1 = coord1 * coord2;
  const myVar2 = myVar1 / coord2 + myVar1;
  return coord1 * (coord2 / myVar2);
}

function generic (f) {
  return function g (x, ...args) {
    return Array.isArray(x)
      ? x.map((el, i) => g(el, ...args.map(arg => arg[i])))
      : f(x, ...args);
  };
}

const myGenericFunction = generic(myFunction);

console.log(myGenericFunction(30, 50));
console.log(myGenericFunction([30, 40], [50, 60]));
console.log(myGenericFunction([[30, 40], [70, 80]], [[50, 60], [10, 20]]));
```

Comment: That is hardcore. I had to run through the code slowly in my head a few times with your test args to figure out exactly how it worked. Question: why do you need myGenericFunction() and generic() at all? Why not call g() directly, and in its "else" statement (the third ternary operand), call myFunction() directly?

Comment: @BoomMike it's intended to be reusable. Any function that takes scalar values as input and returns a scalar value can be passed to `generic()`, and then the returned function will be able to apply the element-wise operation on any dimension input.

Answer (score 0):

> Define Functions per equations.

```
function myFunction( coord1, coord2 ) {
    // Equations
    let e1 = (a,b) => {return a * b;}
    let e2 = (a,b,c) => {return a * b + c;}
    let e3 = (a,b,c) => {return a * (b / c);}

    let myVar1 = 0, myVar2 = 0, myVar3 = 0;

    // if args are arrays
    if ( Array.isArray( coord1 ) ) {
        myVar1 = [], myVar2 = [], myVar3 = [];

        for (let i = 0; i < coord1.length; i++) {
            myVar1[i] = e1(coord1[i], coord2[i]);
            myVar2[i] = e2(myVar1[i],coord2[i],myVar1[i]);
            myVar3[i] = e3(coord1[i],coord2[i],myVar2[i]);
        }

    // else if args are scalar
    } else {
        myVar1 = e1(coord1,coord2);            // this
        myVar2 = e2(myVar1,coord2,myVar1);   // is
        myVar3 = e3(coord1,coord2,myVar2); // inefficient
    }

    return myVar3;
}
```